# How to remove consecutive pairs of opposite numbers from Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

How can i remove consecutive pairs of equal numbers with opposite signs from a Pandas dataframe?

Assuming i have this input dataframe

```py
incremental_changes = [2, -2, 2, 1, 4, 5, -5, 7, -6, 6]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'idx': range(len(incremental_changes)),
    'incremental_changes': incremental_changes
})
```

```
   idx  incremental_changes
0    0                    2
1    1                   -2
2    2                    2
3    3                    1
4    4                    4
5    5                    5
6    6                   -5
7    7                    7
8    8                   -6
9    9                    6
```

I would like to get the following

```
   idx  incremental_changes
0    0                    2
3    3                    1
4    4                    4
7    7                    7
```

Note that the first `2` could either be idx 0 or 2, it doesn't really matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can groupby consecutive equal numbers and transform

```
import itertools

def remove_duplicates(s):
    ''' Generates booleans that indicate when a pair of ints with
        opposite signs are found.
    '''
    iter_ = iter(s)
    for (a,b) in itertools.zip_longest(iter_, iter_):
        if b is None:
            yield False
        else:
            yield a+b == 0
            yield a+b == 0

>>> mask = df.groupby(df['incremental_changes'].abs().diff().ne(0).cumsum()) \
             ['incremental_changes'] \
             .transform(remove_duplicates)
```

Then

```
>>> df[~mask]

   idx  incremental_changes
2    2                    2
3    3                    1
4    4                    4
7    7                    7
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposed solution, however this seems to fail for example in the case when the incremental changes are `[-2, 2, 2, -2, 1, 4, 5, -5, 7, 6, -6]`

Comment: thanks @rafaelc, i upvoted but accepted the other answer because it looks cleaner. I have not compared the performance of the two, but let me know if you think your solution should be preferred

Comment: @crash No worries ! I'm glad we had two answers to your question, which was not trivial :)

Comment: Set this as correct answer because the one from BENY was failing on a case, thanks again rafaelc!

Answer (score 1):

Just do `rolling`, then we filter the multiple combine

```
s = df.incremental_changes.rolling(2).sum()
s = s.mask(s[s==0].groupby(s.ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount()==1)==0
df[~(s | s.shift(-1))]
Out[640]: 
   idx  incremental_changes
2    2                    2
3    3                    1
4    4                    4
7    7                    7
```

Comment: actually your solution doesn't work in this case `incremental_changes = [2, -2, 2, -2, 2, 1, 4, 5, -5, 7, -6, 6]`. Do you have any follow up recommendation? rafaelc solution works instead. Thanks